# Работа cmd с rdp C#/C++

Tags: c#, c++, rdp

Как подключится по RDP в WAN и выполнить какой-нибудь код? например убить процесс

Comment: вы уверены, что правильно понимаете что такое RDP и зачем он нужен? потому что по вашему вопросу пока видно обратное

Comment: да, я правильно понимаю

Comment: тогда ответ никак, если вы не предполагаете писать распознавание образов элементов интерфейса на получаемой картинке

Comment: с помощью AxMSTSCLib не возможно?

Comment: по RDP клиент получает картинку, а передает коды нажатых клавиш, положение и состояние кнопок мыши. Все. Если вы из этого можете что-то извлечь - уточняйте вопрос. RDP - это не удаленная консоль, как например SSH, это всего лишь удаленный монитор.

Comment: а как тогда выполняется запуск программы при подключении? скрин: http://prntscr.com/f7v1vh

Comment: во-первых, программа должна быть на удаленном компьютере. Во-вторых - это параметр создания сессии подключения и не может быть изменено после установления соединения и авторизации пользователя. Т.е. если вызов вашей программы не прописан в настройках *.rdp соединения, то выполнить что либо посторонее после подключения не получится

Comment: понял, спасибо за ответ

Comment: ок, тогда оформлю как тут принято

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) предоставляет удаленный доступ к рабочему столу Windows, но при этом не является удаленной консолью, как например SSH или Telnet подключение. От сервера к клиенту передается изображение удаленного рабочего стола. От клиента к серверу - состояние клавиш мыши, положение мыши в координатах полученного изображения и состояние клавиш клавиатуры.

Таким образом выполнить произвольный код при установленном соединении нельзя. для этого просто не предусмотрено никаких средств. Разве что использовать распознавание образов интерфейса, но это уже извращение и не стоит потраченного времени.

Существует возможность указать в настройках соединения программу, которая будет выполнена при входе пользователя в систему, но, в общем случае, эта программа уже должна быть на удаленном компьютере и у пользователя должны быть привилегии на ее выполнение. Этот механизм срабатывает только в момент создания сессии пользователя, использовать его повторно, после того как соединение было установлено, нельзя.

Возможности монтирования локальных дисков на удаленный сервер, запуска произвольных программ с этих дисков, создания имитации локального соединения, а также привилегии пользователя при удаленном подключении (они могут отличаться от привилегий при локальном подключении), зависят от настроек сервера и желания/умения администратора.

Comment: RDP позволяет запустить одно из приложений за один коннект - один раз. И не запрещено запустить `cmd.exe /C shutdown параметры` или `killprocess` (если позволят привелегии). Имеется ввиду что в самом интерфейсе AxMSTSCLib или раздел Programs ярлыка, прописывается строка команды, и не нужно емулировать клавиши или что-то такое. Главное логин пароль знать.